# Can't activate rails (= 2.3.15), already activated rails-3.2.17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I'm trying to upgrade from Rails 2.3.15 to 3.2.17

I did `bundle update`, and changed controller syntax as needed.

Trying to start the server and I'm getting the following error, is anyone familiar with this?

```
>> bundle exec script/server

 /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:266:in `block in replace_gem': can't activate rails (= 2.3.15), already activated rails-3.2.17. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /Users/neo/src/myapp/config/boot.rb:60:in `load_rails_gem'
        from /Users/neo/src/myapp/config/boot.rb:54:in `load_initializer'
        from /Users/neo/src/myapp/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
        from /Users/neo/src/myapp/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
        from /Users/neo/src/myapp/config/boot.rb:114:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/server:2:in `require'
        from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

#ruby "1.8.7", :group => :staging

gem 'rails', '3.2.17'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3"
gem 'authlogic', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'RedCloth', :require => "redcloth"
gem 'logging'
gem 'panda'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem "comma", "~> 2.0" # specifying -v to add support to rails 2
gem 'pg'
gem 'cloudfront-signer'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'thin'
group :development do
  gem 'heroku'
  gem 'taps'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rdoc'
end
gem 'heroku_san'

group :test do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you

EDIT:

With `rails s` or `bundle exec rails s / server`, I just get the about rails message, like below:

```
rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]                                # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database .
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using

```
bundle exec rails server
```

EDIT: Everything that used to be in the script directory is now managed by the rails command. When upgrading, I found it much easier to use a gemset to isolate the new gems from the old as it was often necessary to switch back and forth, and the new rails command will not play nicely with the old.

Comment: Since you accepted the answer, did you get it working?

Comment: yup, I ran rails new . and solved it, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 using new command syntax for start server, console, scaffold etc.

In rails 3 [script/* got replaced by script/rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#script/*-replaced-by-script/rails)

So, you need to start your server like:

```
rails s
```

OR

```
rails server
```